# Gallery lightbox plugin issue

Tags: css, image, lightbox, image-gallery

I'm developing a website template and just spotted an issue with the gallery lightbox plugin. http://creativusmouse.com/Proteus/html_preview22/portfolio_2_col.html

When the gallery has more than 1 image the lightbox renders just fine but when it has only 1 image the large image wrapper gets smaller than the image.
I kind of spotted what's causing the issue - this template uses foundation 3.0 framework so on foundation.min.css file the very first selector is causing the problem:

```
"    * {
      -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      }
```

I tried to remove this and it fixed the problem however the whole website gets broken.
I'm not sure what code shall I paste here. If necessary I can post a link to download all the template files. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change this code, modify the css for your wrapper instead.  That snippet of code you posted is telling all elements to include any borders, and paddings in the calculation for width.  So a box with 10px of padding and 5px of border space and is 200px wide is actually 200px wide.  Without this code the box would actually be 230px wide.

You could do this...

Add to the class `lightbox-outer` - `overflow: hidden`.

```
.lightbox-outer {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

This works but it hides part of the image, it's like your box doesnt want to scale to the size of the image.

Do you have a setting in the lightbox stuff anywhere that is setting the a specific proportion?

EDIT2:  Something else I found, if I remove "width" from the class .lightbox-skin then it starts behaving again.  Problem is this width is applied to the element inline dynamically?

Comment: Wow it fixed the problem!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! This issue was driving me crazy for hours.

Comment: @user1628193 Out of curiosity, which fix did you implement?  I assume you used the overflow: hidden; method.  Keep in mind that this really isnt a true fix.  It is essentially cutting off part of the image.

Comment: I just added overflow: hidden and it fixed it ;)
I think it's fine if it cuts off part of the image unless there's a better way to avoid this.

Comment: And answering your question: Do you have a setting in the lightbox stuff anywhere that is setting the a specific proportion?
I really have no idea. Probably there is but I can't spot it.

Comment: @user1628193  Some food for thought for another day then...  Somewhere in your lightbox plugin, it is applying a width to the class .lightbox-skin, and it's applying it inline with the HTML element itself.  For whatever reason something about box-sizing: border-box; is getting over-written in the lightbox plugin.  This is causing the aforementioned width to be incorrect, it falls short of how large it should actually be.  You could experiment with adding the box-sizing line of code, to particular elements in your lightbox CSS.  This might fix the actual problem.

Comment: And of course, if you try and figure out the above, make sure you comment out your overflow: hidden; fix, or else you won't be able to tell if it is still broken or not.  Cheers!